# Weird iframe behavior in IE9

Tags: json, internet-explorer, iframe, whitespace

before someone complains, I do not use `iframes` (but while trying to fix a bug, I found the issue is related to a strange behavior that `iframe` is having in IE9, and it was coded by someone else).

I have a JSON which is being sent to an iframe after clicking on Submit:

```
    <a id="general_Submit.Label" class="formActionLink" href="javascript:submitAndSendEmail();"/>

    <form name="fileUploader" id="fileUploader" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="ajaxFileUploadAction.action" target="upload_target">
        <input type="file" name="upload" id="upload" size="40" onchange="dynFileUploader.uploadFile(this);" onkeyup="dynFileUploader.checkValidFile(this)" />
        <iframe name="upload_target" id="upload_target" src="" onload="javascript:dynFileUploader.uploadDone();"> </iframe>
    </form>
```

**THE PROBLEM**

The JSON is being returned correctly by the action:

```
{"JSONClass":"com.lalala.process.email.util.FileContentHolder",
"contentType":"application/pdf","data":[],"fileLength":348364,
"fileName":"001a.<space>bla<space>refrigeration<space><space>-<space>aaa<space>- <space>Tenderer<space>Instructions.pdf",
"tempFileName":"C:\\Users\\humbleUser\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\UPLOADED_7567343180347343279_001a.<space>bla<space>refrigeration<space><space>-<space>aaa<space>-<space>TendererInstructions.pdf"}
```

The issue is in the filename: after there are two whitespaces after the word refrigeration. When we send this json to the iframe, by using `target="upload_target"`, it is arriving in the iframe without one of these whitespaces. for example:

if we have the file: test1.pdf, in IE, it goes to the iframe as test1.pdf

Why do we have this behavior? Of course it doesn't happens in Firefox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see nobody has never faced it, and I conclude it's another behavior for IE, that must consider consecutive whitespaces as only one. While searching, I notice it's a common problem for filenames, as we can see in this [link](http://www.binaryfortress.com/NotepadReplacer/Discussions/View/filenames-with-multiple-consecutive-spaces/?ID=4c64d45b-b748-46f2-bd60-ecbe66b51475).

Anyway, the answer for this question, in my point of view, is that it's a bug from IE.
I solved my bug (when user was trying to upload a file with filename containing several consecutive whitespaces, it wasn't being correctly saved because these whitespaces were being reduced to only one, so I fixed it by replacing whitespaces for underscores and it worked perfectly!)